# ASP.Net: Html.Display()-Method ignores templatename

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, display-templates

I have the following method returning html-code for a model according to the `PropertyInfo` referencing `TDatas` property.

```
 public MvcHtmlString GetHtml(HtmlHelper<TData> helper) {

        if (PropertyInfo.IsDefined(typeof(UIHintAttribute), true)) {
            UIHintAttribute uiHintAttribute = PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UIHintAttribute), true).Cast<UIHintAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (uiHintAttribute != null) {
                // Templatename ignored here
                return helper.Display(PropertyInfo.Name, uiHintAttribute.UIHint);
            }
        }

        return helper.Display(PropertyInfo.Name);
    }
```

The name of the displaytemplate is defined via UIHint and is read out correctly.
So one call could be:

```
return helper.Display("Name", "NameDisplayTemplate");
```

Unfortunatly the `templatename` parameter is ignored when I want to render the property with a specific DisplayTemplate. I tried both displaytemplate (folder displaytemplate) and partialview. None of them worked.

Someone any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't it be helper.Display("UIHint", uiHintAttribute) ?

Comment: According to the docu, the first parameter takes the expression (Propertyname) and the second takes the templatename (UIHint).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the template has to be placed in the DisplayTemplates-Folder, as it is written in the msdn.

> If a template whose name matches the templateName parameter is found
>   in the controller's DisplayTemplates folder, that template is used to
>   render the expression. If a template is not found in the controller's
>   DisplayTemplates folder, the Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates is searched
>   for a template that matches the name of the templateName parameter. If
>   no template is found, the default template is used.